# Gantt Chart for JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, charts, gantt-chart

I've tried using JSGantt and it's really good. But I would like to know if there are other Gantt Chart that offers greater interactivity such as dragNdrop and resizing directly on the chart.

I saw Gxt Gantt but it is not free.
Chart should also be compatible with Java/JSP.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked  [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/)

Here is the sample for [JFreeChartGantt](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/)

Comment: @ice3d can you please tell me what exactly you want to do

Comment: DragNdrop of task to a calendar for better scheduling and UI. Because I've implemented JSGantt in a way that you should schedule on a text based page before displaying the chart. It's so mechanical but it works.

Answer (score 1):

The only free web based Gantt charts I know of are JsGantt and DHTMLxGantt http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxGantt/index.shtml